# Python PicklingError Can't Pickle class...: it's not the same as object

Tags: python, pickle, pythonanywhere

I'm receiving a pickle.picklingerror when running this code and I'm not sure why. I've checked to make sure that there are no conflicting names and I've reviewed similar posts on SO with this error but can't seem to resolve the issue.

This is part 'a' of a 3 part program, where the outfile will be used for parts 'b' and 'c'.

What needs to be changed to resolve this error?

If this post needs to be edited to include additional information I'm happy to do so.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tarnette/assessment7question1a.py", line 80, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/tarnette/assessment7question1a.py", line 15, in main
    dictionaryNations()
 File "/home/tarnette/assessment7question1a.py", line 32, in dictionaryNations
    pickle.dump(nationDictionary, outfile)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Nation'>: it's not the same object as __main__.Nation

 
import pickle

file = "UN.txt"

infile = open("/home/tarnette/UN/UN.txt", 'r')

def main():
    dictionaryNations()

def dictionaryNations():

    nationDictionary = {}

    for line in infile:
        data = line.split(',')

        country = Nation()
        country.setCountryName(data[0])
        country.setContinent(data[1])
        country.setPopulation(float(data[2]))
        country.setArea(float(data[3]))

        nationDictionary[country.getCountryName()] = country

    outfile = open("nationsDict.dat", 'wb')
    pickle.dump(nationDictionary, outfile)
    outfile.close()

    return nationDictionary

class Nation(): ##class named Nation as defined by textbook, THIS WILL ALSO BE SAVED IN A FILE CALLED "nation.py"
    def __init__(self): ##first method, is an initializer, first parameter is self
        self_countryName = "" ##These four variables are the four instance variables that must be created per the project instructions
        self_continent = ""
        self_population = 0.0
        self_area = 0.0

    ##This is the mutator method (change value of instance variable)
    def setCountryName(self, countryName):
        self._countryName = countryName

    ##This is the accessor method (retrieve value of instance variable)
    def getCountryName(self):
        return self._countryName

    ##This is the mutator method (change value of instance variable)
    def setContinent(self, continent):
        self._continent = continent

    ##This is the accessor method (retrieve value of instance variable)
    def getContinent(self):
        return self._continent

    ##This is the mutator method (change value of instance variable)
    def setPopulation(self, population):
        self._population = population

    ##This is the accessor method (retrieve value of instance variable)
    def getPopulation(self):
        return self._population

    ##This is the mutator method (change value of instance variable)
    def setArea(self, area):
        self._area = area

    ##This is the accessor method (retrieve value of instance variable)
    def getArea(self):
        return self._area

    ##This accessor method retrieves value of the calculation made for population density. Titled popDensity per project instructions.
    def popDensity(self):
        return (self._population / self._area)

main()
```

Comment: The error message indicates that the code that actually produced that error message is not quite the same as the code you posted. I suspect the actual code has a second `Nation` class or something like that.

Comment: Also, please don't quote-format error messages. Code-format them, to preserve exact details of spacing and make sure stuff in angle-brackets shows up properly. Exact details of error messages often matter, down to individual space characters.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I'll be sure to format the error messages differently moving forward.
Unfortunately, the code I posted is what I copy-pasted from my PythonAnywhere console, I've searched the code for a second Nation class, but there doesn't appear to be any second instance.

Comment: Your `Nation` class is commented as *THIS WILL ALSO BE SAVED IN A FILE CALLED "nation.py"*.  Does that file actually exist, and if so, are you `import`ing it anywhere?  `pickle` is somehow finding a different definition of `Nation` than you used when creating your dictionary, and this seems like a possible cause - an imported class will never be identical to one defined directly in your code, even if the definitions are character-for-character identical.

Comment: @jasonharper That "nation.py" file does exist, it can be found in the files of my PythonAnywhere account, but it is not imported into this program.
Could the error have something to do with my "country = Nation()" statement? Would that be a potential source of a duplicate `Nation`?